# qooxdoo: Firefox 59 table selection not accepted

Tags: firefox, qooxdoo

There is a new behaviour in Firefox 59 for table selection.

I use the selectionMode: qx.ui.table.selection.Model.MULTIPLE_INTERVALL_SELECTION_TOGGLE
I get the multiple rows selected with the getSelectedRanges method.

A customer found out, that from Firefox version 59.0.1 the table does not show rows selected when using the left mouse clicks. (It works only with right mouse clicks).

Before Firefox 59 one could select a row with mouse click.

What should i do? Is it something that needs to be fixed in qooxdoo?

I use qooxdoo 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This problem seams to be solved with qooxdoo 5.0.2